# Parse string starting from the end

Tags: java, string

I want to split string around only the last `_` character , example:`some_string_foo_bar` into two substrings `some_string_foo` `bar`.

I tried to use `Pattern` and `StringTokenizer`, but they always start from the beginning of stirng. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: In C# we have `LastIndexOf`, in C we have `strrchr`. Don't tell me there isn't anything like that in Java.

Answer (score 5):

Use [lastIndexOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)); there's no reason to do a full split.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) might be of some use. Here's an example.

```
String source = "hello_world_foo";
int pos = source.lastIndexOf('_');
String before = source.substring(0, pos);
String after = source.substring(pos + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String strX = "some_string_foo";
String str1 = strX.substring(0,strX.lastIndexOf("_"));
String str2 = strX.subscting(strX.lastIndexOf("_"),strX.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arr = str.split("_");
String lastOne = arr[arr.length-1];
```